Milnor’s claim in his book Topology form the differentiable viewpoint
In the appendix of Milnor’s book Topology from the differentiable viewpoint, it is shown that any $1$ smooth and connected sub manifold is diffeomorphic to the circle or an interval.
However in the proof of the extension lemme (in the section on the Brouwer degree), when he used this result on $F^{1}(y)$ where $F$ is a smooth map between sub manifolds and and $y$ a regular value, he claims moreover that it is a finite union of circles and arcs.
I do not see why it is true ? From the classifying theorem we know that it is diffeomorphic to a circle or an interval, there is no mention of union of arcs and circles.
If you have some helps to provide I will be glad please. Thank you !

You missed a connected requirement somewhere

You are right thank you !
